# All the datas in my Node.js request page are written as [object object]

Tags: javascript, node.js

All the data in my node js request web page are displayed as [object object].

I have tried parsing my data which created a new error which nothing will be displayed. Same thing as i was gonna stringify the data results same error will occur which is nothing is being displayed. (Note that my data is stored in a handlebar extension file).

My API Method

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  let sql = "SELECT * FROM qname";
  db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    res.render('index', { title: 'Project', result });
  });
});
```

As for my Index.handlebar

```
<h1 class="text-center">{{title}}</h1>
<h4><br><br>Queue Counts:</h4>
<ul class="list-group">
{{#each result}}
<li class="list-group-item">
{{this}}
</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify()` on `result` to convert your object to a string

Comment: I did convert it to a string but it made things worse no data is being displayed in the request web page.

Comment: My current data in console.log

[ TextRow { idqName: 1, qNameCount: 'Kirnese' },
  TextRow { idqName: 2, qNameCount: 'Klaus' },
  TextRow { idqName: 3, qNameCount: 'Kaiser' },
  TextRow { idqName: 4, qNameCount: 'Kristy' },
  TextRow { idqName: 5, qNameCount: 'Kolby' } ]

Comment: Stringified data in console.log
[{"idqName":1,"qNameCount":"Kirnese"},
{"idqName":2,"qNameCount":"Klaus"},
{"idqName":3,"qNameCount":"Kaiser"},
{"idqName":4,"qNameCount":"Kristy"},
{"idqName":5,"qNameCount":"Kolby"}]

Comment: With `if (err) throw err;` you do not handle the error case correctly. If an error occurs you create a dangling request. (e.g. if `db` for some reason loses the connection to the database server you will make your application unresponsive in a short amount of time and it will stay unresponsive even after the db connection is active again.)

Comment: Thank you for the advice i have changed the error handling already but it still doesn't  help my problem with the data in the request page as [object object].

Answer (score 0):

You should be more clear on the scope of your issue. It would help if you could explain specifically what are you trying to do.

I've understood that you're trying to parse data form a database and send the results to a specific template, right?

First and foremost, never miss indentation on your code. Without indentation it is way harder to understand. I've fixed that for you:

```
app.get('/', (req,res) => { 
  let sql="SELECT * FROM qname";
  db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(result);

    res.render('index', {
      results,
      title: 'Project'
    });
  });
});
```

Your code looks right. What databsae are you using? Have you tried to query the database directly to see the result? It appears that you've tried to add a JSON object inside the database directly, so it has saved the string "[object Object]" on the database record.

Comment: Okay thank you any suggestions? Do i delete the data in my current database and store new ones by POST Method?

Comment: @Kirnese don't ask new questions in the comment section. The comment sections is used to clarify any uncertainty/problems regarding the answer. If you have a follow-up question then ask it as a new question. Which HTTP request methods should be used for what task is completely unrelated to your original question.